# Android SQLite: how to use rawquery with Order By and Descending function?

Tags: php, android, database, sqlite

I'm not really familiar with android programming but still i can understand codes, my only problem is that i cant get the outputs that i need for my game app on android eclipse, i just wanted to retrieve data's from my database and display the highscores from 3 different textfield for example:

```
TextField1 <-- this will be the highest score of a player will be displayed
TextField2 <-- this will be the second highest next to textfield1
TextField3 <-- this will be the third highest score
```

I'm really out of luck coding i thought this will be easy like doing things in PHP but sucks for me im a newbie in android, if someone can help me please do :)

BTW: this is the code that i've been working but i dont have any luck to display what i wanted

```
try{ 
db = openOrCreateDatabase("DodgerDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null); 

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from ScoresTable order by scoreVALUE desc",null);

while(c.moveToNext()){ 
scoreid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreID"));

score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreVALUE")); 

date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scoreDATE")); 


ScoreView1.setText("score id:"+scoreid+" score:"+score+" date:"+date); 

ScoreView2.setText("score id:"+scoreid+" score:"+score+" date:"+date); 

ScoreView3.setText("score id:"+scoreid+" score:"+score+" date:"+date); 

}//end of while loop }//end of try statement 

catch(Exception er) { 
Toast.makeText(ScoresActivity.this, ""+er, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

still i got only have same indentical (datas) output coming from database on those 3 fields please help :(

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will see only the last row from your cursor. Each iteration retrieves a row from Cursor, and previous values in `TextView` are overwritten each time.

Try this to understand how it works:

```
while(c.moveToNext()){ 
scoreid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreID"));

score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreVALUE")); 

date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scoreDATE")); 

Log.d("SomeTag", "score id:"+scoreid+" score:"+score+" date:"+date); 

}
```

UPD: To show your 3 rows in different TextViews:

```
c.moveToNext();
scoreid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreID"));
score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreVALUE")); 
date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scoreDATE")); 
ScoreView1.setText("score id:"+scoreid+" score:"+score+" date:"+date); 

c.moveToNext();
scoreid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreID"));
score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreVALUE")); 
date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scoreDATE")); 
ScoreView2.setText("score id:"+scoreid+" score:"+score+" date:"+date); 

c.moveToNext();
scoreid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreID"));
score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("scoreVALUE")); 
date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scoreDATE")); 
ScoreView3.setText("score id:"+scoreid+" score:"+score+" date:"+date);
```

Comment: yeah i only got the last data but its the max value, so i need the 2 more data to be displayed in those 2 textfield, i'm running out of idea, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Added update. You also have to add checks if cursor is not empty and count is not less than 3

Comment: wow man you really help me thanks a lot for your time i appreciate it, i'll let you know if it works :) thanks

Comment: hi man thanks for the help it works :) thank you so much, now i can finally past my school project and submit it hahaha